# Behavioral Game Theory Reference Request

Tags: game-theory, reference-request

I am interested in studying behavioral game theory, particularly in incomplete information games. However, I am having trouble finding a current "textbook" like source to learn from. I've been reading over Colin Camerer's book *Behavioral Game Theory: Experiments in Strategic Interaction*, however, I was curious whether there was something more recent/updated (as it's from 2003, if I recall correctly). I've found various articles on JSTOR and similar databases, but it hasn't been as fruitful an endeavor as I had hoped. Any recent text suggestions/places to look would be sincerely appreciated. (If the text I brought up is considered the "gold standard" for the field, pardon my ignorance; I've only recently started looking into the topic.)

Comment: it would be nice if you could be a bit more specific about the kind of topics you want to learn about. Are you interested in the theory, or experimental evidence? I can comment on the former. I believe you can begin with misspecified models - Esponda and Puozo's Berk Nash equilibrium is a good starting point. You can also look up papers by Eyster and Rabin, and Levy and Razin (they have series of papers on different behavioural issues like correlation neglect, biased reasoning). Finally you can look up the Handbook of Behavioural Economics to get a large set of papers on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm certainly more interested in the theory side of things. In particular, I am hoping to eventually apply what I learn to research various card games (most interested in No Limit Hold'em and PLO). I'll definitely look at your recommendations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know a bunch of people who teach behavioral economics using [Erik Angner's book](https://www.macmillanihe.com/page/detail/a-course-in-behavioral-economics-erik-angner/?sf1=barcode&st1=9781137512925).
I love Rani Spiegler's book on behavioral economics in IO called ["Bounded Rationality and Industrial Organization."](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bounded-Rationality-Industrial-Organization-Spiegler/dp/0199334269/ref=sr_1_1_twi_pap_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1510521553&sr=8-1&keywords=ran%20spiegler) Both books will introduce models that can be applied to poker.

Perhaps a little lighter but still scientific readings would be [Kahneman's "Thinking, Fast and Slow"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11468377-thinking-fast-and-slow) or [Ariely's "Predictably Irrational."](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1713426.Predictably_Irrational)

As already suggested, a "handbook" is always a good place to start: [Handbook of Behavioral Economics - Foundations and Applications.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/handbook/handbook-of-behavioral-economics-applications-and-foundations-1/vol/1)